# Splitting a column based on select character?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many columns. For one of the columns ('cols'), it roughly has this structure:

'x\y\z'

Some of the rows are 'x\y\z' and others are 'x\y'. I am only interested in the 'y' portion of the row.

I have been looking through various posts on stackoverflow by people with similar questions, but I have not been able to find a solution that works. The closest that I got was this (which resulted in an error):

`x = strsplit(df['cols'], "\")`

I have a feeling I may not be utilizing a package correctly. Any help would be great!

Edit: Included sample structure and expected output

Current structure:

```
     cols
'test\foo\bar'
'test\foo'
'test\bar'
'test\foo\foo'
```

Expected output:

```
 cols
'foo'
'foo'
'bar'
'foo'
```

Comment: @RonakShah I have made the edit. I cannot give the actual data but this is almost identical to what the structure is. This would be one column among maybe ~75 that is in the dataset. Please let me know if you need any more clarification and thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to escape

```
df$cols <- sapply(strsplit(df$cols, "\\\\"), `[`, 2)
df$cols
#[1] "foo" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub("^\\w+.(\\w+).*", "\\1", df$cols)
#[1] "foo" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(cols = c("test\\foo\\bar", "test\\foo", "test\\bar", 
"test\\foo\\foo")), .Names = "cols", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am getting this error: 'Error in strsplit(df2$cols, "\\\\") : non-character argument'

Comment: @rmahesh The error is due to the `class` of 'cols'.  May be you have a `factor` class, converrt it to `character` i.e. `strsplit(as.character(df2$cols), "\\\\")`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at a great package for data manipulation: [`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/)

Then:

```
df = tidyr::separate(df, col = cols, into = c("x", "y", "z"), sep="\\\\")
```

(note the escaped backslash)

Comment: NB: I wrote this just before you gave your example, not sure anymore that it really corresponds to what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you for the response Pierre! Example is identical to what I was describing earlier. My question would be would this consistently work even if some has 2 '\' and others have 3 '\'?

Comment: Yes, it will work too, with a warning. See argument `fill` of the function to control this behaviour

Comment: Running into an error. So that actual column is called "Iteration.Path". Because it has a period, I am getting an "Error in stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) : 
  Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)"

Comment: It is not linked to the column name, it's my bad: you need 4 backslashes to make it work (because `sep` is a regular expression). I just fixed it in my answer, but akrun's answer is fine too.